# Stop asp:PlaceHolder from removing whitespaces

Tags: asp.net, whitespace

I came across some strange behavior of `asp:PlaceHolder`, it removes whitespaces between the `asp:Literal`s within it.

For example for this code:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text="aa" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" Text="bb" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Literal ID="Literal3" Text="cc" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<asp:Literal ID="Literal4" Text="dd" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

The output will be `aabb cc dd`.

Is there is a way to stop it from removing the whitespaces (and not by adding `&nbsp;` between the literals or `Text="aa "`)?

Comment: why do you want this? it will be alot harder to refactor for you and others in the future

Comment: @Kim I want it, because this is how it's supposed to work. If the literals are first name and last name, I want a space between them...

Comment: Just ran into this and just about pulled my hair out.  I wasn't able to reproduce on a clean new website, so I started pulling out tags until I identified the placeholder as the culprit.  After that it was easy to find this post.  I still don't understand why it would ever be designed this way, assuming it's not a bug.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386790/placeholder-does-not-preserve-whitespace  "Thank you for the report, this is actually intentional. Placeholder is not normally user in markup like this, it is essentially a 'marker' within a page..."  So if it's JUST a marker, why remove whitespace?  I still don't get it...

Comment: @NelsonRothermel You can see from @pOcHa's answer that this is intentional. Look at the `AllowWhitespaceLiterals` override in `PlaceHolderControlBuilder`. Still not sure why it designed that way...

Comment: I just came across the same problem. Has someone found any other solution other than overriding placeholder or using Panel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to simply override `PlaceHolder`:

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CustomControls
{
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:Holder ID='Holder1' runat='server'></{0}:Holder>"), ControlBuilder(typeof(ControlBuilder))]
    public sealed class Holder: PlaceHolder
    {
    }
}
```

The key here is using `ControlBuilder` instead of `PlaceHolderControlBuilder`, which just overrides it to always return `false` for `AllowWhiteSpaceLiterals`.

You use it as any other web control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="CustomControls" %>
<asp:Holder runat="server">...</asp:Holder>
```

Answer (score 6):

I came up with two solutions:

**First:** To replace the `asp:PlaceHolder` with `asp:Panel`. The disadvantage is that you get a wrapping `div`.

**Second:** To put an empty HTML comment between the `literals`

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text="aa" runat="server"></asp:Literal><!>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" Text="bb" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And yes, `<!>` is a legal HTML comment.

Comment: for a real solution have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would either surround it with a  or use a asp:label rather than a literal. You would have a lot more control over how it is going to use. With the span - give it a class or an id and you can target it to make it look how you like.

Alternatively roll your own Literal. It would not be that hard but you might miss some of the other stuffs that come with it.

A third alternative is to create an interim string that you can bind to / use as an input into the literal. This would have the aa bb in an ensured format.

Comment: With `asp:Label`, we have the same problem, anyway I prefer not to add additional elements to the HTML.